# How can i Set the Region color for each state in Geochart?

Tags: google-visualization

i want to set the region color for each state in the United states like in the image?
is it possible in geochart?

Please guide me to do that.

Thanks &Regards,
Ranjith Kumar.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I have built in the past a 'political' map also, with the google geochart API. 
Here's the code I used for the US:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

  function drawVisualization() {var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

 data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Value'); 
 data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'});var ivalue = new Array();

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-AK',f:'Alaska'},0,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-AK'] = 'Obama (D)  will <span style="color:#444; font-weight:bold;">win</span> in Alaska.';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-AL',f:'Alabama'},1,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-AL'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Alabama';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-AR',f:'Arkansas'},2,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-AR'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Arkansas';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-AZ',f:'Arizona'},3,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-AZ'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Arizona';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-CA',f:'California'},4,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-CA'] = 'Obama (D) will win in California';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-CO',f:'Colorado'},5,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-CO'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Colorado';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-CT',f:'Connecticut'},6,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-CT'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Connecticut';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-DE',f:'Delaware'},7,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-DE'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Delaware';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-FL',f:'Florida'},8,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-FL'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Florida';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-GA',f:'Georgia'},9,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-GA'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Georgia';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-HI',f:'Hawaii'},10,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-HI'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Hawaii';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-IA',f:'Iowa'},11,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-IA'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Iowa';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-ID',f:'Idaho'},12,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-ID'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Idaho';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-IL',f:'Illinois'},13,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-IL'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Illinois';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-IN',f:'Indiana'},14,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-IN'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Indiana';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-KS',f:'Kansas'},15,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-KS'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Kansas';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-KY',f:'Kentucky'},16,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-KY'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Kentucky';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-LA',f:'Louisiana'},17,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-LA'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Louisiana';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-MA',f:'Massachusetts'},18,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-MA'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Massachusetts';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-MD',f:'Maryland'},19,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-MD'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Maryland';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-ME',f:'Maine'},20,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-ME'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Maine';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-MI',f:'Michigan'},21,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-MI'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Michigan';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-MN',f:'Minnesota'},22,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-MN'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Minnesota';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-MO',f:'Missouri'},23,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-MO'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Missouri';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-MS',f:'Mississippi'},24,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-MS'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Mississippi';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-MT',f:'Montana'},25,'Obama (D)']]);
 ivalue['US-MT'] = 'Obama (D) will win in Montana';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-NC',f:'North Carolina'},26,'Romney (R)']]);
 ivalue['US-NC'] = 'Romney (R) will win in North Carolina';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-ND',f:'North Dakota'},27,'Romney (R)']]);
 ivalue['US-ND'] = 'Romney (R) will win in North Dakota';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-NE',f:'Nebraska'},28,'Romney (R)']]);
 ivalue['US-NE'] = 'Romney (R) will win in Nebraska';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-NH',f:'New Hampshire'},29,'Romney (R)']]);
 ivalue['US-NH'] = 'Romney (R) will win in New Hampshire';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-NJ',f:'New Jersey'},30,'Romney (R)']]);
 ivalue['US-NJ'] = 'Romney (R) will win in New Jersey';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-NM',f:'New Mexico'},31,'Romney (R)']]);
 ivalue['US-NM'] = 'Romney (R) will win in New Mexico';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-NV',f:'Nevada'},32,'Romney (R)']]);
 ivalue['US-NV'] = 'Romney (R) will win in Nevada';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-NY',f:'New York'},33,'Romney (R)']]);
 ivalue['US-NY'] = 'Romney (R) will win in New York';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-OH',f:'Ohio'},34,'Romney (R)']]);
 ivalue['US-OH'] = 'Romney (R) will win in Ohio';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-OK',f:'Oklahoma'},35,'Romney (R)']]);
 ivalue['US-OK'] = 'Romney (R) will win in Oklahoma';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-OR',f:'Oregon'},36,'Romney (R)']]);
 ivalue['US-OR'] = 'Romney (R) will win in Oregon';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-PA',f:'Pennsylvania'},37,'Romney (R)']]);
 ivalue['US-PA'] = 'Romney (R) will win in Pennsylvania';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-RI',f:'Rhode Island'},38,'Romney (R)']]);
 ivalue['US-RI'] = 'Romney (R) will win in Rhode Island';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-SC',f:'South Carolina'},39,'Romney (R)']]);
 ivalue['US-SC'] = 'Romney (R) will win in South Carolina';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-SD',f:'South Dakota'},40,'Romney (R)']]);
 ivalue['US-SD'] = 'Romney (R) will win in South Dakota';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-TN',f:'Tennessee'},41,'Romney (R)']]);
 ivalue['US-TN'] = 'Romney (R) will win in Tennessee';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-TX',f:'Texas'},42,'Undecided']]);
 ivalue['US-TX'] = 'People are Undecided in Texas';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-UT',f:'Utah'},43,'Undecided']]);
 ivalue['US-UT'] = 'People are Undecided in Utah';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-VA',f:'Virginia'},44,'Undecided']]);
 ivalue['US-VA'] = 'People are Undecided in Virginia';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-VT',f:'Vermont'},45,'Undecided']]);
 ivalue['US-VT'] = 'People are Undecided in Vermont';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-WA',f:'Washington'},46,'Undecided']]);
 ivalue['US-WA'] = 'People are Undecided in Washington';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-WI',f:'Wisconsin'},47,'Undecided']]);
 ivalue['US-WI'] = 'People are Undecided in Wisconsin';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-WV',f:'West Virginia'},48,'Undecided']]);
 ivalue['US-WV'] = 'People are Undecided in West Virginia';

 data.addRows([[{v:'US-WY',f:'Wyoming'},49,'Undecided']]);
 ivalue['US-WY'] = 'People are Undecided in Wyoming';

 var options = {
 backgroundColor: {fill:'#FFFFFF',stroke:'#FFFFFF' ,strokeWidth:0 },
 colorAxis:  {minValue: 0, maxValue: 49,  colors: ['#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#E0D39E','#E0D39E','#E0D39E','#E0D39E','#E0D39E','#E0D39E','#E0D39E','#E0D39E']},
 legend: 'none',    
 backgroundColor: {fill:'#FFFFFF',stroke:'#FFFFFF' ,strokeWidth:0 },    
 datalessRegionColor: '#f5f5f5',
 displayMode: 'regions', 
 enableRegionInteractivity: 'true', 
 resolution: 'provinces',
 sizeAxis: {minValue: 1, maxValue:1,minSize:10,  maxSize: 10},
 region:'US',
 keepAspectRatio: true,
 width:600,
 height:400,
 tooltip: {textStyle: {color: '#444444'}, trigger:'hover'}  
 };
  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization')); 
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
  var selection = chart.getSelection();
  if (selection.length == 1) {
  var selectedRow = selection[0].row;
  var selectedRegion = data.getValue(selectedRow, 0);
  if(ivalue[selectedRegion] != '') { alert(ivalue[selectedRegion]); }
  }
  });
 chart.draw(data, options);
 }
 </script>
 <div id='visualization'></div>
```

This is how the map looks like:

[image: US Political Map Example]

You can see it in live action here on my website, along with other geochart map examples with codes: http://cmoreira.net/interactive-maps-generator/examples.html

Answer (score 3):

Well, the first place you should look is at google's geochart API found here:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Note the options object. Give it a property of region set to 'US' and a resolution of 'provinces'. Something like this:

```
var options = {
    region: 'US',
    resolution: 'provinces',
    //other options...,
}
```

Now this will get you the states, but it won't color them. To do that you'll need to set values for each state. Do it like this:

```
var state_value_array = [
['State', 'race_state'],
['Georgia', 3],
['Alabama, 3],
['New Mexico, 1],
//Other 47 states...,
];
```

The first value is the state and the second is the value it carries for coloring. To get the coloring you want you'll have to massage the data a bit then set the color range you want.

```
options['colorAxis'] = {colors: ['blue', 'grey', 'red']};
```

Call draw on the chart object and pass the state_value_array array to the arrayToDataTable object and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

To set the region color for each state as the below image you have to use colors property in the options object.Try this below code

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Country', 'Site'],
            ['Alabama', 0],
            ['Alaska', 1],
            ['American Samoa', 2],
            ['Arizona', 3],
            ['Arkansas', 4],
            ['California', 5],
            ['Colorado', 6],
            ['Connecticut', 7],
            ['Delaware', 8],
            ['District of Columbia', 9]
]);


var options = {width: 556, height: 347};
    options['region'] = 'US';
    options['resolution'] = 'provinces';
    options['colors'] = ['#4bb5f3', '#FADC41', '#c44949', '#d74a12', '#0e9a0e', '#55c2ac', '#7c4b91', '#fadc41', '#0d6cca', '#7c4897'];
```

Take a look at this [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-set-the-region-color-for-each-state-in-geochart/) that has a working sample

Comment: Swarma -- welcome to StackOverflow! The best answers will contain code or explanation that adds to answers not already here. Explaining how to use it is going to be more useful to future visitors than just posting a link. See [CMoreira's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17299415/1933347) or [shefHauwanga's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17282661/1933347) for good examples!